# Flyout menu is not visible in pages in xamarin forms

Tags: logging, xamarin.forms, menu, flyout, app-shell

I created a new project with default template containing already a login button, logout button etc. I followed a tutorial step-by-step which creates login and register. After logging in, you are redirected to HomePage. In my home page the flyout menu is not visible.

**here is the code from my LoginPage.xaml.cs**

```
namespace final1scratch.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
    {
        public LoginPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BindingContext = new LoginViewModel();
        }

   async void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new RegistrationPage());
    }

    async void Handle_Clicked_1(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var dbpath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "UserDatabse.db");
        var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbpath);
        var myquery = db.Table<RegUserTable>().Where(u => u.UserName.Equals(EntryUser.Text) && u.Password.Equals(EntryPassword.Text)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (myquery != null)
        {
            App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new HomePage());
        }

        else
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                var result = await this.DisplayAlert("Error", "Failed User Name and Password", "Yes", "Cancel");

                if (result)
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new LoginPage());
                else
                {
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new LoginPage());
                }

            });
        }
    }
}
```

**And here is my HomePage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="final1scratch.Views.HomePage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
            
            <Button Text="Logout" Clicked="Handle_Clicked" TextColor="Black"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**Here is a screenshot after the user has logged in**

[click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4uPB.png)

Comment: Is that default template using Xamarin.Shell?

Comment: @NikolaosEfentis From your description, maybe you can post some code about Xamarin.shell xaml code, don't know where do you put login or home page.

Comment: @Shaw I started the project with flyout menu by default and made some changes.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT do you want to upload any other file in order to understand?

Comment: @NikolaosEfentis Yes, you can also upload your project at github or onedrive, I will downloa your sample to test, it is better for us to understand your problem.